# Get div width value after changing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/fresa150/fs5Ya/1/

Try to get value of div width after finish of its animation.
For example when you click the circle3 and line width became 100px - something should happend with circle1, when line goes to 230px - something should happent with circle2.

```
<div id="menu-holder">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="line-holder">
      <div id="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="circle1" class="c"></div>
    <div id="circle2" class="c"></div>
    <div id="circle3" class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>

var load = $('#line');

    $('#circle1').click(function w(){
      load.animate({width:"100px"},1000, function(){
        $('#circle1').css('background','#840101');
      });

    });

    if(load.width() == 100) {
    alert('some thing should happend with circle1');
    }

    $('#circle2').click(function(){
      load.animate({width:"230px"},1000, function(){
        $('#circle2').css('background','#840101');
      });
    });

    if(load.width() == 230) {
    alert('some thing should happend with circle2');
    }


    $('#circle3').click(function(){
      load.animate({width:"350px"},1000, function(){
        $('#circle3').css('background','#840101');
      });
    });
```

Comment: You need to put your width code into each of the callback events that happen when animate completes! They are asynchronous operations.

Comment: you've already used the complete callback for the `#circle1`, so you should have known how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your width code into each of the callback events that happen when animate completes! They are asynchronous operations.

Your tests for specific widths are then pointless (as they will be at those widths on completion).

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fs5Ya/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var load = $('#line');

    $('#circle1').click(function w() {
        load.animate({
            width: "100px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#circle1').css('background', '#840101');
            alert('some thing should happend with circle1');
        });
    });

    $('#circle2').click(function () {
        load.animate({
            width: "230px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#circle2').css('background', '#840101');
            alert('some thing should happend with circle2');
        });
    });


    $('#circle3').click(function () {
        load.animate({
            width: "350px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#circle3').css('background', '#840101');
        });
    });

});
```

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fs5Ya/4/

You wanted to run the previous links in sequence, so you needs to nest that same code for each previous section. e.g. circle 3 click animates to circle 1, then circle 2 then circle 3:

```
$('#circle3').click(function () {
    load.animate({
        width: "100px"
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#circle1').css('background', '#840101');
        load.animate({
            width: "230px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('#circle2').css('background', '#840101');
            load.animate({
                width: "350px"
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#circle3').css('background', '#840101');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

There is a shorter alternative (but more complicated), running 1, 2 or 3 of them in parallel with different start (`delay`) times, but this is clearer for now.

Comment: maybe I did not properly describe my problem,one more exemple: when you click on third circle whe load width became 100px - the background of circle1 must became red, and so on, when load width 230px - cirle2 bg-color :red

Comment: @Mongo: Oh, you want to chain the animations. That needs a complete overhaul. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: tnx very much, waiting for your idea